# Django Template Hyperlink missing WSGIScriptAlias

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, mod-wsgi

I have a Web App using Django 1.7.4 and Apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi

I have this in my httpd.conf

```
Listen 8999
WSGIScriptAlias "/BusApp" "D:/BusApp/BusApp/wsgi.py"
```

In my template I am creating a Hyperlink like this

```
<a class="item" href='/Range'>Range</a>
```

So 127.0.0.1:8999/BusApp should lead to my WSGI Application. And it does.

From there all links should get prepended with "http://127.0.0.1:8999/BusApp" Is that a correct understanding?

Currently the hyperlink that i indicate above takes me to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8999/Range
```

instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1:8999/BusApp/Range
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

No, WSGI does not modify any links you hard code into your templates. How could it?

However, if you ask Django to generate the link via the `{% url %}` template tag - which you should be doing anyway - Django will know about the mount point of your app, and create the link accordingly including prefix.

Comment: In Django 1.6.1 it used to work even when it was hardcoded. Is this a recent Change?